# Android SAXParser : Not well-formed document ... That *do* is well-formed

Tags: android, xml, file, saxparser

So, I have a launcher activity, where the user selects a file (in fact, a directory, containing a .xml and a .wav).

When he clic on the file he wants to open, I start a new activity which works with the previously selected files.

- display files to user
- Launcher_Activity :
  onClick :
      Other_Activity.path_dir = file.getAbsolutePath();
      startActivity(Other_Activity_Intent);
- Other_Activity :
  file_source = new InputSource(new StringReader( path_dir + "/xml.xml" ));
  parser.parse(file_source)

> ParseException : At line 1, column0: not well-formed (invalid token)

it's like the XML file was empty ... but, I know that my path_dir is the right one, and my xml file is at the right place also

I also know that it is well-formed because I was using it before.
In a previous version of the app, the .xml and .wav were "in-app" so I was using

> file_source = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xml));

Using raw resource was working.
But i'm trying to put the resource outside of the app
and my XML document is no longer recognized ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<text>
    <lots of tag .../>
</text>
```

Ther's not typpo in the xml ... Does anyone have a clue ?

---

EDIT :

```
file_source = new InputSource(new StringReader( path_dir + "/xml.xml" ));
file_source.setEncoding("UTF-8");
parser.parse(file_source);
```

It seems to avoid the bad-formed Exception ... But the app' crash somewhere else, I have to track down where ...

Comment: Where is your file and are you accessing the file the same way as raw resources?

Comment: the file is located at : 
`/mnt/storage/My_app_dir/an_other_dir/xml.xml`
The value of path_dir is :
`/mnt/storage/My_app_dir/an_other_dir`
so, path_dir + "/xml.xml" is the right place.

I'm accessing the xml file using :
`file_source = new InputSource(new StringReader( path_dir + "/xml.xml" ));`

Comment: Is the InputSource printing correctly if you log it before parsing?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "printing correctly" ... Before I start parsing, the value of the InputSource is not null, and point to `/mnt/storage/My_app_dir/an_other_dir/xml.xml` ...

I found a little probleme. I'll edit that ...

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant is, if you log the contents of xml.xml before attempting to parse, does it print correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging the inputstream that you are getting.

I don't know about InputSource much, but I guess, there's some problem of reading the file properly.

Try using this instead

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("path to file));
parser.parse(fis);
```

Comment: `The method parse(InputSource) in the type XMLReader is not applicable for the arguments (FileInputStream)`
... That's why I was using InputSource

Comment: Ooops. Hmm, Anyway, you can create an InputSource from InputStream. new InputSource(input_stream)

Answer (score 0):

Put the xml file in the `/assets` folder and then use this line:

```
parser.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("xml.xml")));
```

Comment: I don't want to put my XML inside /assets because I want to put ressources "outside" of the app'

Comment: Oromis clearly states that he is "trying to put the resource outside of the app".

Answer (score 0):

XML files inside res directory are "pre-compiled" into a binary form.

That is why you are getting the error

```
ParseException : At line 1, column0: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Move it into the asset directory as someone else suggested, and you will be able to read it the way you want to.   Hint: the asset folder is "outside the app" to exactly the same extent that the res folder is.  Ie. not at all.